# marque will not displayed error comes as validation xhtml1.0

Tags: asp.net

This is my code it shows error message as validation xhtml1.0 transitional lement marquee is not displayed

```
.header
{
 width: 100%;
 background-color: green;
 height: 80px;
}


<body>
<form runat="server">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <marque  behavior="scroll" direction="right">
        <div class="header">
            <a href="/default.aspx" ><img src="images/wave.gif" width="100" height="65" border="0" alt="HOME -- Xefteri-Articles for Web Developers"/></a>

        </div>
        </marque>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table> 
</form>
</body>
```

suggest a  suitable method

Answer (score 0):

You have written `<marque>` tag ,
actually it is `<marquee>`. try changing it to `<marquee>` it may work

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that your marquee is not working?

I have tried using `<marquee>` tag it works fine for me